# Telerik Multiple Charts MVC (Stacked Bars?)

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

Does anyone know if it's possible to achieve the desired chart in Telerik. Essentially, it's a chart that displays a weeks usage of a particular machine. The usage is broken down into the hour slots of a day (please ignore the colour coding).

[image: Daily Usage]